# Parse Log File - Reading from the end first

Tags: vb.net

Having some trouble with a log file I need to parse and display certain fields in a data grid view.  The log file is a large tab delimited file and I can read it and parse the array easily.  The issue is that I want to start at the END of the file and read backwards until I hit a certain value in one of the fields.  Then I want to start reading forward again until it hits the end of the file.  While it's reading to the end I want it to fill the data grid view with certain fields.  Here's what I have so far -

Looking at the code - it needs to read from the end until the 4th field equals zero and then start reading forward again.  I can also read from the end, saving the values to the data grid view as I go until I hit that 0 if that's easier.

Thanks for the help!

The other option would be to read the file and save it in reverse, line by line - the last line first, the 2nd to last line 2nd, etc.  That would be really nice as I have another function that will need to read the file and it also needs to go from the end to the beginning.

```
  Private Sub btnParseLog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnParseLog.Click

    Dim FileLocation As String = "BLAHBLAHBLAH"
    Dim LogFile As String = "LOGFILE"

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True

    ' Set the column header style. 
    Dim columnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()

    columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
    columnHeaderStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle


    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "User"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Number"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Time"

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(LogFile)

        MyReader.TextFieldType =
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}


        Dim TotalLineCount As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(LogFile).Length

        Dim currentRow As String()

        Dim RowCount As Integer = 0

        'Loop through all of the fields in the file.  
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing.  
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData

            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                RowCount = RowCount + 1
                ' Include code here to handle the row. 

                If RowCount = TotalLineCount Then

                    While Not currentRow(4).ToString = 0

                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow(1).ToString, currentRow(4).ToString, currentRow(7).ToString)

                        RowCount = RowCount - 1

                    End While

                End If

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                " is invalid.  Skipping")

            End Try

        End While

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "a large tab delimited file", do you mean a few KB or several 100MB?

Comment: It varies but the file I'm working with to test (which is an actual log file) is 2.58 mb and 23,021 lines long.

Comment: Have you tried reading the entire file in (which you happen to do anyway when you use `File.ReadAllLines(LogFile).Length`) and parsing it, then working from the parsed data? You could use a DataTable or a List(Of T) to store all the data then filter it somehow for display. TBH, reading a file backwards is rather awkward.

Comment: I could try either of those.  I'd much rather read and save the file backwards though.  Seems easier.

Comment: OK, all you need to do is figure out how to reliably read a UTF16 string backwards. Good luck! ;)